# Extra padding on border

Tags: html, css, border, margin, padding

I am getting extra padding added on my bottom border on hover. Is there a way to get rid of the extra padding?

I have tried:

```
#nav a:hover, #nav a:focus {
   border-bottom: solid 3px #000;
   padding: 0;
}
```

but that makes the menu item move because original padding is being removed from it.

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
  <div class="menu-main-container">
    <ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-33 current_page_item menu-item-47"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-43"><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav ul {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav li {
    font: 400 18px/13px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav a {
  padding: 0 16px;
  color: #343434;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#nav a:hover, #nav a:focus {
  border-bottom: solid 3px #000;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygewjby9/1)**

Comment: try to put `#nav a { line-height:0;border-bottom:0px;}`

Comment: or check this one, https://jsfiddle.net/ygewjby9/3/

Comment: @mmativ doesn't work because there is extra padding on the border still

Comment: you talking about the width of your `border-bottom`?

Comment: if you want to add border and same width with your text try this one, https://jsfiddle.net/ygewjby9/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because border is added over the padding layer in `css box model` It goes like First and innermost is padding, then border and then margin. To fix this you need to do the following:

Instead of this:

```
#nav li {
  font: 400 18px/13px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav a {
  padding: 0 16px;
  color: #343434;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Do this:

```
#nav li {
  padding: 0 16px; /* added here*/
  font: 400 18px/13px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav a {
  /*padding: 0 16px;*/ /* removed from here*/
  color: #343434;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygewjby9/5/)